# How to route from OpenVPN server to OpenVPN client on the same host?

Tags: routing, openvpn

My topology includes HostA running OpenVPN client connecting to server on HostB. HostB has OpenVPN client connecting to server on HostC. Both tunnels are open and I can send curl requests through each but I cannot get traffic routed from HostA, through HostB, to HostC. For example:

```
        Public          Private         Client Tunnel   Server Tunnel
HostA   1.1.1.1         10.120.177.168  10.8.0.6        10.8.0.1
HostB   2.2.2.2         172.30.24.54
HostC   3.3.3.3         10.140.17.141   10.9.0.6        10.9.0.1

HostA $ ip address
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc prio state UP group default qlen 1000
        inet 10.120.177.168/26 brd 10.120.177.191 scope global eth0
    20: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
        inet 10.8.0.6 peer 255.255.255.0/32 scope global tun0
HostB $ ip address
    4: eth0@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
        inet 172.30.24.54/32 scope global eth0
    18: tun010140017141: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
        inet 10.9.0.6 peer 10.9.0.5/32 scope global tun010140017141
    20: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
        inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
HostC $ ip address
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc prio state UP group default qlen 1000
        inet 10.140.17.141/26 brd 10.140.17.191 scope global eth0
    227: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 32000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
        inet 10.9.0.1 peer 10.9.0.2/32 scope global tun0
```

[image: VPN Routing Example]
OpenVPN configuration:

```
HostA $ cat /etc/openvpn/client.conf
    client
    remote 2.2.2.2 443
    proto tcp
    dev tun
    nobind

HostB $ cat /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
    port 443
    proto tcp4
    dev tun
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
    push "route 10.140.17.141 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.6"
    client-config-dir ccd
    route 10.120.177.168 255.255.255.255
HostB $ cat /etc/openvpn/server/ccd/gateway_10_120_177_168
    ifconfig-push 10.8.0.6 255.255.255.0
    iroute 10.120.177.168 255.255.255.255
HostB $ cat /etc/openvpn/client/tun010140017141/client.ovpn
    client
    remote 10.140.17.141 1194
    proto tcp
    dev tun010140017141
    nobind

HostC $ cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
    port 1194
    proto tcp
    dev tun
    server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

- I have omitted the parts of the configuration related to certificates and logging since that works.

Kernel routing:

```
HostA $ ip route
    default via 10.120.177.129 dev eth0
    10.0.0.0/8 via 10.120.177.129 dev eth0
    10.8.0.1 via 255.255.255.0 dev tun0
    10.120.177.128/26 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.120.177.168
    10.140.17.141 via 10.8.0.6 dev tun0
    255.255.255.0 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.6

HostB $ ip rule list table my_routing_table
    32764:  from 10.140.17.141 lookup my_routing_table
    32765:  from 10.120.177.168 lookup my_routing_table
HostB $ ip route list table my_routing_table
    10.120.177.168 dev tun0 scope link
    10.140.17.141 dev tun010140017141 scope link
HostB $ ip route
    default via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0
    10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
    10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
    10.9.0.1 via 10.9.0.5 dev tun010140017141
    10.9.0.5 dev tun010140017141 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.6
    10.120.177.168 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
    169.254.1.1 dev eth0 scope link

HostC $ ip route
    default via 10.140.17.129 dev eth0
    10.0.0.0/8 via 10.140.17.129 dev eth0
    10.9.0.0/24 via 10.9.0.2 dev tun0
    10.9.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.1
    10.120.177.168 via 10.140.17.129 dev eth0
    10.140.17.128/26 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.140.17.141
    192.168.0.0/16 via 10.140.17.129 dev eth0
```

I want to accomplish:

```
HostA $ curl -v https://10.140.17.141
```

but the response is

```
* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
```

The traffic does come from HostA, over the tunnel to HostB

```
HostB $ tcpdump --interface=tun0 -n host 10.140.17.141
    12:55:07.039521 IP 10.8.0.6.44150 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [S], seq 2877997232, win 42340, options [mss 1358,sackOK,TS val 3699256805 ecr 0,nop,wscale 12], length 0
    12:55:07.039629 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44150: Flags [S.], seq 1620656485, ack 2877997233, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 19053367 ecr 3699256805,nop,wscale 9], length 0
    12:55:07.046763 IP 10.8.0.6.44150 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 11, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699256831 ecr 19053367], length 0
    12:55:07.205307 IP 10.8.0.6.44150 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:178, ack 1, win 11, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699256988 ecr 19053367], length 177
    12:55:07.205377 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44150: Flags [.], ack 178, win 131, options [nop,nop,TS val 19053533 ecr 3699256988], length 0
    12:55:07.206243 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44150: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 178, win 131, options [nop,nop,TS val 19053534 ecr 3699256988], length 0
    12:55:07.392219 IP 10.8.0.6.44154 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [S], seq 3637655375, win 42340, options [mss 1358,sackOK,TS val 3699257178 ecr 0,nop,wscale 12], length 0
    12:55:07.392277 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44154: Flags [S.], seq 1233055697, ack 3637655376, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 19053720 ecr 3699257178,nop,wscale 9], length 0
    12:55:07.412840 IP 10.8.0.6.44154 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 11, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699257199 ecr 19053720], length 0
    12:55:07.419864 IP 10.8.0.6.44154 > 10.140.17.141.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:319, ack 1, win 11, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699257206 ecr 19053720], length 318
    12:55:07.419895 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44154: Flags [.], ack 319, win 131, options [nop,nop,TS val 19053747 ecr 3699257206], length 0
    12:55:07.420618 IP 10.140.17.141.https > 10.8.0.6.44154: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 319, win 131, options [nop,nop,TS val 19053748 ecr 3699257206], length 0
```

but does not make it to the other interface

```
HostB $ tcpdump --interface=tun010140017141 -n host 10.140.17.141
    nothing
```

I am confused why the tcpdump indicates that 10.140.17.141 is responding.

I am able to talk to HostC from HostB using the tunnel

```
HostB $ curl -v https://10.9.0.1
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

which responds with the page I expect from

```
curl -v https://10.140.17.141
```

To prove it is using the tunnel

```
HostB $ tcpdump --interface=tun010140017141 -n
    13:09:45.950403 IP 10.9.0.6.45884 > 10.9.0.1.https: Flags [S], seq 226912329, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 879082581 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
    13:09:45.995483 IP 10.9.0.1.https > 10.9.0.6.45884: Flags [S.], seq 845398301, ack 226912330, win 31948, options [mss 1358,sackOK,TS val 3700256992 ecr 879082581,nop,wscale 12], length 0
    13:09:45.995550 IP 10.9.0.6.45884 > 10.9.0.1.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 128, options [nop,nop,TS val 879082626 ecr 3700256992], length 0
    13:09:45.995727 IP 10.9.0.6.45884 > 10.9.0.1.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 128, options [nop,nop,TS val 879082626 ecr 3700256992], length 517
    13:09:46.043310 IP 10.9.0.1.https > 10.9.0.6.45884: Flags [.], ack 518, win 9, options [nop,nop,TS val 3700257036 ecr 879082626], length 0
    13:09:46.043468 IP 10.9.0.1.https > 10.9.0.6.45884: Flags [.], seq 1:1347, ack 518, win 9, options [nop,nop,TS val 3700257038 ecr 879082626], length 1346
    ...
```

Since HostB has the route

```
10.140.17.141 dev tun010140017141 scope link
```

why is the request not relayed?

Comment: Have you enabled ip forwarding (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`)?

Comment: and as also  NAT?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, IP forwarding was enabled, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` -> 1, `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` -> "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1".

Comment: I can see multiple problems: (2 strange routes with 255.255.255.0 *as unicast* or *as gateway*  probably because OpenVPN didn't use subnet topology somewhere. Can be ignored) 1/ HostA uses the wrong source address so HostB never triggers a special routing 2/ HostC doesn't have the correct route to reply to HostA (be that the wrong or correct IP) 3/ some traffic in the tcpdump test is probably routed through 169.254.1.1 which breaks RFC 3927. Fixing HostA manually is easy, I don't know how to do it with OpenVPN's configuration. but with multiple issues I'm sure something else also lurks around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved Network Address Translation and masquerading using nftables and openvpn iroute commands in Client Configuration Directory files. Here are the changes:

```
HostB $ nft list ruleset
    table inet filter {
        set cluster-ips {
            type ipv4_addr
            elements = { 10.140.17.141 }
        }

        set tunnel-nets {
            type ipv4_addr
            elements = { 10.120.177.168 }
        }

        set ports-allowed {
            type inet_service
            elements = { 443, /* other ports needed by applications */ }
        }

        chain INPUT {
            type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
            ip saddr @tunnel-nets tcp dport @ports-allowed ip daddr @cluster-ips accept
            ip saddr @tunnel-nets udp dport @ports-allowed ip daddr @cluster-ips accept
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
            type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
            ip saddr @cluster-ips ip daddr @tunnel-nets accept
        }

        chain FORWARD {
            type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
            iifname "tun0" oifname "tun010*" ct state established,related counter
            iifname "tun010*" oifname "tun0" ct state established,related counter 
        }
    }
    table ip nat {
        set downstream_ports_allowed {
            type inet_service
            elements = { 443, /* other ports needed by applications */ }
        }

        set upstream_ports_allowed {
            type inet_service
            elements = { 22, /* other ports needed by applications */ }
        }

        chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
            ip daddr 10.140.17.141 iifname "tun0" tcp dport @downstream_ports_allowed counter dnat to 10.141.67.5
            ip daddr 10.120.177.168 iifname "tun010*" tcp dport @upstream_ports_allowed counter dnat to 10.120.177.168
        }

        chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
            oifname "tun0" masquerade
            oifname "tun010*" masquerade
        }
    }
HostB $ cat /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
    client-config-dir ccd
    topology subnet
    push "route 10.140.17.141 255.255.255.255"
    route 10.120.177.168 255.255.255.255
HostB $ cat /etc/openvpn/server/ccd/gateway_10_120_177_168
    iroute 10.120.177.168 255.255.255.255
HostC $ cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf
    client-config-dir ccd
    topology subnet
    route 10.120.177.168
HostC $ cat /etc/openvpn/ccd/tun010140017141
    iroute 10.120.177.168
```